# Old Commented Out Settings in Rails Apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Files like `config/application.rb` and a lot of the Rails boilerplate include helpful reference comments  like

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb ...
# config.i18n.default_locale = :de
...
```

possibly waiting to be enabled.  My question is, when moving from Rails 2 to Rails 3 to Rails 4 (and in the future to Rails 5), how should you think about these?

Flags and settings will throw deprecation warnings because minor and major versions but obviously not when they are commented out.  I can imagine a situation where a setting was generated in Rails 2 and then mistakenly enabled in Rails 5, skipping deprecation warnings.

Rails 2 to 3 upgrade had a gem that would help you along.  Presumably these comments were ignored because they aren't run.  Tests won't pick them up.  I think maybe a static analysis tool would be able to help but I don't know of any.

You could just remove all these comments carte-blanche and then look up any definitions for the version you are on in the documentation I suppose.  Maybe it's not an issue because normal CI / Test / deploy checks would pick up on any deprecated or wrong settings so you'd be protected by this.

I'm more interested in a tool that removes commented out settings before deployment or anyone with a long-running app that has made a decision on these commented-out settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files generated by different versions of rails contain different code + reference comments, relating to the specific set of configuration items for that version of rails. Config & the related comments for one version might be not useful for another version.

One way to ensure that the application has the right content (including comments) in the configuration files, is the compare the content of each file with a dummy rails app generated for that specific version.

I upgraded a rails app from rails versions 2.3.18 to 4.2 via 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0 & 4.1, and at each step, comparing with a dummy app created with the target version of rails made it for a quicker upgrade, giving greater confidence about the code in the new version.

I doubt if any automated tool could have helped in this effort.